# Error on compiling MongoDB C++11 driver

Tags: c++, mongodb, c++11, mongo-cxx-driver

I'm trying to compile MongoDB C++11 driver with the following CMake command.

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" \
"-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=../installation/cxx-driver" \
"-DLIBBSON_DIR=../installation/libbson" \
"-DLIBMONGOC_DIR=../installation/c-driver" \
"-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=../installation" \
"-DBOOST_ROOT=E:/Softwares/Libraries/Boost/boost_1_64_0" \
../mongo-cxx-driver-r3.1.1
```

Got the following error.

```
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'bson.h': No such file or directory
```

The 'bson.h' file exists in the following path

```
../installation/libbson/include/libbson-1.0
```

My expectation is either the `-DLIBBSON_DIR` or the `-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` directives would help showing where include directory is. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does it work if you specify absolute paths for each of the variables?

Comment: Have you solve your problem？ I have the problem with you.

Comment: @Sucy, not at all. All my attempts have been in vain so far. Any idea?

Comment: Look at my answer, I have solve this problem. Good luck to you!

Answer (score 0):

Remove unnecessary quotes:

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" \
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=../installation/cxx-driver \
-DLIBBSON_DIR=../installation/libbson \
-DLIBMONGOC_DIR=../installation/c-driver \
-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=../installation \
-DBOOST_ROOT=E:/Softwares/Libraries/Boost/boost_1_64_0 \
../mongo-cxx-driver-r3.1.1
```

Comment: I did remove the quotes and still got the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I have spend about two days to solve this problem. Thanks goodness! I have solved it.   where you configure your mongo-c-driver? No matter where you configure it, like /usr, /usr/local, or /usr/local/xxx(any name), you can find that the mongoc.h and others header files are all under libmongoc-1.0 folder, you should copy all the header file(xxxx.h)out of the libmongoc-1.0 folder and under include folder and that is will be ok. Good luck! this three configure path I all test it. Good luck!